# Codelite able to build with 0 errors but showing '.../build-Debug/lib: no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, codelite

I've created a workspace and a project for the first time with the default code like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The "Build" says 0 errors, 0 warnings. But when the terminal is run it's showing:

```
MY-MBP ~ % /tmp/codelite-exec.sh ; exit;
/tmp/codelite-exec.sh: line 3: cd: /Users/ME/Desktop/Personal/Projects/ProjectName/build-Debug/lib: No such file or directory
```

I am using Mac OS Catalina and using gcc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

## Change your executable path

- Right-Click on your project folder `ProjectName`
- chose `settings`
- under `General > Executable to Run / Debug` change the path to your executable

In your example this should be: `/Users/ME/Desktop/Personal/Projects/ProjectName/build-Debug/bin/ProjectName` where `ProjectName` is your executable.